# Sonatype Nexus 3 stuck on OnLine - Ready To Connect status for proxies

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory

I have installed Nexus several times before, but Nexus 3 seems to be a bit different. Taking a basic installation running on Docker, after a few minutes Nexus reports the remote Central proxy as Online - Remote Available. However, I cannot find the perennial asset 'junit'.

I have a non-docker install which is my production install on a multihomed machine. This machine remains for ever stuck on Online - Ready to Connect status. I have tried urlpoke.jar from this machine and I have full communications to the Central repo.

I appreciate the deletion of dialogs and buttons was a design goal but its working against you. Nexus2 was much simpler in this regard and I suggest you resist dummyfication when attempting simplification. You are not apple, and apple fails horribly at this too, just see how people google basic operations on itunes, because iTunes really is a pathetic UI experience which only gets worse with each update.

Please help Sonatype OSS project, or is it time to move to Artifactory?

Comment: Proxy means that the dependencies will be visible in Nexus if you have requested it from a build/tools for the first time...?

Comment: Is that a statement or a question? In nexus2 I could query Central and more for any asset I had never loaded. Is this feature suddenly not desirable? Is the purpose of a Proxy to only list items it has stored locally? If this is true then developers and leaders who have no clue what they are doing have been allowed to destroy a good product - fire them and replace them with people whose understanding includes the knowledge that you are not the future if you don't understand your past! - Besides, the behavior should be that Nexus goes out and downloads the remotes index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was related to authentication. I had set LDAP as an authentication source and this was allowing me to log in and administer the UI, but not allowing me to access the proxies. Not sure why I did not resolve it.

The entire lot only worked again, without LDAP, when I reinstalled it and blew away my prior configuration.

Although I can now PULL assets from my proxied back-ends, I cannot search the backends.

Nexus 2 used to download or build an index from the backend proxied maven sites, and we used to be able to query our nexus 2 searching for any artifact in the backend proxied sites. For some reason, I don't have this working still. If this feature has been deprecated, Nexus 3 has gravely missed the mark and can no longer effectively be considered as a Maven Repository IMO.

Comment: Year is 2020 and I have this problem with searching proxied sites. Did you get any update about this?

Answer (score 8):

The "Online - Ready to Connect" just means that the repository is working, and it will connect as soon as you make a request into Nexus that triggers an outbound request to the proxy's remote.  Try running a build against Nexus.

Comment: As much as i'd like to believe this, when the repository sits in "Online - Ready to Connect" for 4 hours, repeatedly trying to get something from it, something else is wrong... except logging doesn't tell us anything.